# Parse text between multiple lines - Python 2.7 and re Module

Tags: regex, python-2.7, delimiter

I have a text file i want to parse. The file has multiple items I want to extract. I want to capture everything in between a colon ":" and a particular word. Let's take the following example.

```
Description : a pair of shorts
amount : 13 dollars
requirements : must be blue
ID1 : 199658
----
```

The following code parses the information out.

```
import re

f = open ("parse.txt", "rb")
fileRead = f.read()

Description = re.findall("Description :(.*?)amount", fileRead, re.DOTALL)
amount = re.findall("amount :(.*?)requirements", fileRead, re.DOTALL)
requirements = re.findall("requirements :(.*?)ID1", fileRead, re.DOTALL)
ID1 = re.findall("ID1 :(.*?)-", fileRead, re.DOTALL)

print Description[0]
print amount[0]
print requirements[0]
print ID1[0]

f.close()
```

The problem is that sometimes the text file will have a new line such as this

```
Description 
: a pair of shorts
amount 
: 13 dollars
requirements: must be blue
ID1: 199658
----
```

In this case my code will not work because it is unable to find "Description :" because it is now separated into a new line. If I choose to change the search to ":(.*?)requirements" it will not return just the 13 dollars, it will return a pair of shorts  and 13 dollars because all of that text is in between the first colon and the word, requirements. I want to have a way of parsing out the information no matter if there is a line break or not. I have hit a road block and your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you make it `r'Description\s+...'`, allowing multiple whitespace characters (including newlines)?

Comment: hahahaha, such an easy fix. I've been going crazy over it. That did it, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
Description[^:]*(.*)
   ^--- use the keyword you want
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM4oR1/1)**

Quoting your code you could use:

```
import re

f = open ("parse.txt", "rb")
fileRead = f.read()

Description = re.findall("Description[^:]*(.*)", fileRead)
amount = re.findall("amount[^:]*(.*)", fileRead)
requirements = re.findall("requirements[^:]*(.*)", fileRead)
ID1 = re.findall("ID1[^:]*(.*)", fileRead)

print Description[0]
print amount[0]
print requirements[0]
print ID1[0]

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
import re
f = open ("new.txt", "rb")
fileRead = f.read()
keyvals = {k.strip():v.strip() for k,v in dict(re.findall('([^:]*):(.*)(?=\b[^:]*:|$)',fileRead,re.M)).iteritems()}
print(keyvals)
f.close()
```

Output:

```
{'amount': '13 dollars', 'requirements': 'must be blue', 'Description': 'a pair of shorts', 'ID1': '199658'}
```